# GORM Object Relation is not loaded in an async block

Tags: java, grails, asynchronous, groovy, grails-orm

I use Grails GPaars to create an async block.

In BuildConfig:

```
compile 'org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.1'
compile 'org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0'
```

I defined a helper Class:

```
class TaskService {

  private ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool()

  /**
   * Executes the given closure in a new thread.
   * @param args is a map of arguments to be used in the async closure.
   * @return
   */
  def executeAsync(args, closure = null) {
    if(!closure) {
      closure = args
      args = null
    }

    GParsPool.withExistingPool(pool) { closure.callAsync(args) }
  }
}
```

Now in a controller I do:

```
TrackingEmail tEmail = TrackingEmail.get(trackingEmailId)
Device targetDevice = tEmail.device
```

The former works the `device`is retrieved from the TrackingEmail object.

Now I try to do the same in an async block:

```
taskService.executeAsync(trackingEmailId: trackingEmailId) { data ->
   TrackingEmail tEmail = TrackingEmail.get(data.trackingEmailId)
   Device targetDevice = tEmail.device
}
```

In this async block only `tEmail`is retrieved from the database. The second line is not executed.

**How do I get relational objects in an async block?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should use GPars for GORMing directly. In this case you would have to take care of transactions/sessions yourself:

```
 taskService.executeAsync(trackingEmailId: trackingEmailId) { data ->
   Device.withTransaction{ tx ->
     TrackingEmail tEmail = TrackingEmail.get(data.trackingEmailId)
     Device targetDevice = tEmail.device
   }
}
```

and that would give you bad performace in case of frequent parallel calls.

I'd recommend to take a look at [Asynchronous Programming in Grails](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/async.html), which uses the extended GPars

Comment: Yep! I've used grails.async.Promises.task successfully. And it does require .withTransaction().